# The app crashes when trying to use auto spelling correction

Tags: bug, android-app

I am using the Stack Overflow Android app on my Moto G4 Plus Android phone (Android OS 7.0). In the app, when I try to use auto spell correct functionality from the keyboard, the app crashes. I've tried this multiple times, but every time it crashes.

Scenario:

I was commenting/answering in someone's question and I wrote something wrong, which shows me red underline for that incorrectly spelled word.
When I try to use auto spell correction hint from my keyboard, the app crashes every time.

Comment: Have you tried using this functionality in other apps? It seems more likely that it's the autocorrect functionality causing the crash, than something in the app.

Comment: In other apps like whats app, facebook or others it's working fine but not with SO.

Comment: Same here. Hundreds of apps and as far as I know spellcheck works across all the rest. In the SE app it crashes it hard every time. Just trying to place the cursor while writing comments turns into a lost-data nightmare.

Comment: What keyboard is this? Stock Android? Swiftkey? Or something similar?

Comment: For me its Gboard

Comment: I've been unable to replicate this. I see the crash in my crash logs, and it seems to only be happening on the G4 and Droid Turbo 2, so it might be a Motorola 7.0 bug only. A [related SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39234832/android-n-crashes-in-textappearancespan) (with the same stacktrace I see) has an answer saying it's fixed by using the latest support library, which we already are -- I'm investigating this.

Comment: @Kasra As you have mentioned this is Motorola 7.0 bug only, then it should not work for other apps also but it's working like a charm for others(Whats app, Facebook, Instagram etc.)

Comment: @Kasra This is not a Motorola bug. I'm on a LG Nexus 5 with Lineage OS.

Comment: @ReadyAndroid not saying it's a Motorola bug, sorry, just meant that the only crashes in my crash logs are from two Motorola devices. Looks to not be the only ones where it happens, but I still have no repro or attempted fix.

Answer (score 1):

Our app was experiencing the same issue.  Recent Samsung devices with Android 7.0 installed.  We were able to fix the problem by having our Activities extend `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

The changelog doesn't mention anything about it but this issue went away for me in the just released 1.0.94 version.